# Ansible - environment variables

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

How to read the environment variables present inside the .env file located at target machine. Note: I don't know what are all the variables inside the .env file. I need to get the all the variables inside the env file and use them in environment keyword. How to do this in playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are after the 'ansible_facts'?

these are all the facts that are gathered when ansible touched a hosts.

You can read more about it here - https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-facts-list-how-to-use-ansible-facts/